# Galois group of $x^3-x^2-4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In determining the Galois group of the polynomial $p(x) = x^3-x^2-4,$ I concluded that is must be the Klein-$4$ group as follows. First, $p(x) = (x-2)(x^2+x+2)$ and the roots of the irreducible quadratic $x^2+x+2$ are:
$$x_{1,2} = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}.$$ Therefore, the splitting field of $p(x)$ is
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i).$ Since this is a biquadratic extension and none of $i, \sqrt{7}$ and $\sqrt{7}i$ are squares, the Galois group is then Klein-$4$ group.

However, I found two different answers that disagree with mine. First is from the Dummit and Foote. Specifically, on page 612 it states that:

> If the cubic polynomial is reducible and it splits to a linear factor and an irreducible quadratic, it's Galois group is group of order $2.$

The second source is [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/Math121/Solutions7.pdf), where it proceeds to conclude that the polynomial is *irreducible* and also its Galois group is $S_3,$ on page $5.$

What is the correct answer here?

Comment: Is the splitting field not $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7}i)$?

Comment: Well, I agree 2 is a root. Therefore Dummit and Foote are right. The problem with your answer is that you've got the splitting field wrong. See Cheerful Parsnip's comment above.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, actually you are right. I don't know what I was thinking. $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of its roots and so the group must be of order $2$ too.

Comment: It's all good. That's how we learn.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip maybe you should write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interests of moving this question off the unanswered queue, I'm converting my comment to an answer:

The splitting field is actually $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7}i)$. Also, the second source is clearly wrong, since $2$ is a root.